# How can I see if this line is an isdn30 line?

Tags: voip, cisco-voip

I got an port here from somewhere, and I'm guessing its an isdn30 line but I'm not sure. How can I check if its indeed an isdn30 line? I can plug my laptop in with an utp-cable but is there a program which can detect which line it is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it's not ethernet, so you cannot *plug it into your laptop*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the port you are specking about called controller and for 30 it will be E1 . its format will be something like E1 0/0/0 .
so by issue ***sh controllers E1***  you will get some thing like

*E1 0/0/0 is up.

  [Omitted]

E1 0/0/1 is down.

  [Omitted]*

the UP one is the CONNECTED one

to check the status of the ISDN ,issue the command ***sh isdn status***

*Global ISDN Switchtype = primary-net5

ISDN Serial0/0/0:15 interface

        dsl 0, interface ISDN Switchtype = primary-net5

    Layer 1 Status:

        ACTIVE

    Layer 2 Status:

        TEI = 0, Ces = 1, SAPI = 0, State = MULTIPLE_FRAME_ESTABLISHED

    Layer 3 Status:

        0 Active Layer 3 Call(s)

    Active dsl 0 CCBs = 0

    The Free Channel Mask:  0xFFFF7FFF

    Number of L2 Discards = 0, L2 Session ID = 6

    Total Allocated ISDN CCBs = 0*

the most importunate here ,the status of layer 1 which ***active***   indicating that connection is establish and every thing going well